# A more elegant secondary sort for arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need to perform a sort on an array and if two elements are equal I then need to perform a secondary sort on a different key within those elements. Having a look at the Mozilla Developer Network docs for [array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) there is a nice snippet at code at the bottom to handle the first sort. I liked it because it was succinct and shows how you can write powerful JS.

Here is what I tried based on the code from MDN. This correctly does the first sort.

```
// the array to be sorted
var list = [{name:'Delta', ref: 456}, {name:'Delta', ref: 123}, {name:'alpha', ref: 789}, {name:'CHARLIE', ref: 012}, {name:'bravo', ref: 345}];

// temporary array holds objects with position and sort-value
var mapped = list.map(function (el, i) {
  return {
    index: i,
    value: el.name.toLowerCase(),
    secondaryValue: el.ref
  };
});

// sorting the mapped array containing the reduced values
mapped.sort(function (a, b) {
  return +(a.value > b.value) || +(a.value === b.value) - 1;
});

// container for the resulting order
var result = mapped.map(function (el) {
  return list[el.index];
});

console.log(list);
console.log(result);
```

Now I know I can modify the comparison function like this to complete the requirement of the secondary sort:

```
// sorting the mapped array containing the reduced values
mapped.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (a.value === b.value){
    return +(a.secondaryValue > b.secondaryValue) || +(a.secondaryValue === b.secondaryValue) - 1;
  }

  return +(a.value > b.value) || - 1;
});
```

But, to me, this loses some of the charm of `return +(a.value > b.value) || +(a.value === b.value) - 1;` - which is pretty cool in my opinion.

**Question**: Is there a more elegant way to perform the secondary sort?

*Restriction*: Pure JS only. ES5 compatible preferably but interested to hear if ES6 can help.

Comment: If it makes you happier, you can always do `return +(a.value === b.value ? a.secondaryValue > b.secondaryValue || +(a.secondaryValue === b.secondaryValue) - 1 : a.value > b.value) || - 1;`

Comment: I'd use a util function that takes multiple sort functions as parameters: `multisort(arr, primarySortFn, secondarySortFn, ...)` and keep the logic separate.

Comment: I feel like this is primarily an opinion based question and would fit better on [codereview.se]

Comment: @zzzzBov Perhaps, but I am interested in learning about tricks and shortcuts in JS such as +(boolean) and || that is not opinion.... it's just something I don't know. Thank you for your previous answer btw.

Comment: @piratemurray, the problem is that the question "what are some cool tricks i can use to make this code better?" doesn't have a single objective correct answer. I feel like this question falls on the interesting end of subjective, but it's still subjective and opinion based.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can chain the sort comparison with a logic or `||`, because same values are evaluated to `0` and that is falsy so the next part is evaluated.

```
mapped.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (+(a.value > b.value) || +(a.value === b.value) - 1) ||
        (+(a.secondaryValue > b.secondaryValue) || +(a.secondaryValue === b.secondaryValue) - 1);
});
```

Or use more compact version of the above comparison

```js
var list = [{name:'Delta', ref: 456}, {name:'Delta', ref: 123}, {name:'alpha', ref: 789}, {name:'CHARLIE', ref: 12}, {name:'bravo', ref: 345}],
    mapped = list.map(function (el, i) {
        return {
            index: i,
            value: el.name.toLowerCase(),
            secondaryValue: el.ref
        };
    });

mapped.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.value.localeCompare(b.value) || a.secondaryValue - b.secondaryValue;
});

var result = mapped.map(function (el) {
    return list[el.index];
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm on the fence about answering this so I'm going to answer the question of:

> How can an array be concisely sorted by multiple sorting functions?

The question isn't exactly what you're asking, but this way it's a little better defined and answerable.

---

Sorting an array with a single function is pretty straightforward using `Array.prototype.sort`, but unfortunately wasn't forward-thinking enough to allow for *multiple* parameters. It also has the problem of modifying the array directly rather than being chainable:

```
a = [2, 1, 3];
a.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b - a;
});
```

Sorting by multiple dimensions is trickier because all dimensions need to be accounted for in the `sort` callback, or you need to write your own sorting algorithm, which is irksome.

If you're using underscore or lodash, there are various sorting utilities available which are convenient, but if you're not using another library a `multisort` function isn't overly difficult, you can feel free to use the one i whipped up quickly which I haven't hardly tested:

```
multisort = (function () {
// or for commonjs
// module.exports = (function () {
    function slice(arr) {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(arr);
    }

    // multisort(arr, [fn1], [fn2] ...)
    return function multisort(arr) {
        var args;

        //copy the arguments into a new array
        args = slice(arguments);

        //copy the array to a new array and sort the new array    
        return slice(arr).sort(function (a, b) {
            var i,
                fn,
                res;

            //iterate over the sort callbacks
            for (i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
                fn = args[i];
                //call the sort callback,
                //this version doesn't do anything special with setting a context
                res = fn(a, b);
                //if the sort value is anything other than 0, return it
                //otherwise fall to the next sort function
                if (res) {
                    return res;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        });
    }
}());
```

You'd use it as:

```
mapped = multisort(mapped, function (a, b) {
    return +(a.value > b.value) || +(a.value === b.value) - 1;
}, function (a, b) {
    return +(a.secondaryValue > b.secondaryValue) || +(a.secondaryValue === b.secondaryValue) - 1;
});
```

This format keeps the sorting functions distinct from one-another, so that they can be mixed and matched in whatever order you'd prefer.

Answer (score 0):

What about a helper like this?

```
function thenby(comparer, func) {
    return function (a, b) {
        var intermidiate = comparer(a, b);
        if (intermidiate)
          return intermidiate;
        else
          return func(a, b)
    };
}
```

Then you can write comparers and string them together

```
var comparer = function (a, b) {
    return +(a.value > b.value) || +(a.value === b.value) - 1;
};

comparer = thenby(comparer, function (a, b) {
    return +(a.secondaryValue > b.secondaryValue) || +(a.secondaryValue === b.secondaryValue) - 1;
});

mapped.sort(comparer);
```